# Registration with Google Credentials In an Android application

Tags: java, android, single-sign-on

I want my users to register in my Android app with a Google username & password. How can I do this?

Can anybody provide sample code for it or can explain it Step by Step. I went through many documents but didn't find any solution for it.

Comment: the link was unedited before,now its edited and my answer is unnecessarily voted down..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing you can use is [Google+ Sign In](https://developers.google.com/+/features/sign-in). Alternatively, you can use the basic Google OAuth2 flow, though that's harder to integrate (the AccountManager makes it look somewhat user-hostile as well).